# Apache routes trafic from port 80 to other port

Tags: apache, node.js, routes

I have an Apache server handling many VirtulServers and everything works fine. I don't know how it works internally but it does.

I recently tinkered a bit with nodejs, making experiments on this server, on the 8080 port. Now that I want to go on production, I have set up a domain name pointing to my server, but I want to avoid the ugly example.org:8080/ URL that I have at the moment. How could I tell Apache, which is listening on 80, to route traffic from example.org to 123.12.12.123:8080 and vice-versa, without breaking access to the other VirtualServers?

I have tried ModRewrite [L] but specifying the port and domain forces it to appear in the address bar of a browser, which is even uglier. I have tried ModRewrite [P] and ProxyPass but to no success (both give 500 error). What should I try next?

Answer (score 1):

Use the mod_proxy module instead of mod_rewrite.

You need these lines:

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass http://example.org http://123.12.12.123:8080
ProxyPassReverse http://example.org http://123.12.12.123:8080
```

That's it. 
Oh, and yes, that is ProxyPass OFF. not ON.

Comment: Actually I was doing everything right, the proxy_http module was jsut not loaded :/